# How can I filter from a reactive dataset using dplyr?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, reactive

I can't filter a reactive dataset. I need to call different datasets on my pc according to the user input; since those datasets have the same row names I want to define a single filter for them.
For this question I made two simple datasets. Thank you so much in advance.

UI

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(selectInput('number', h4("Select number"), 
choices = c("first", "second")),
    selectInput('dataset', h4("Select dataset"),
    choices=c("dataset1",
    "dataset2"))),

    mainPanel(
    plotOutput("graph")
    )))
```

SERVER

```
server <- function(input, output) {

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


dataset1 <- data.frame(names=c("first", "second"), 
X1=rnorm(1:10),X2=rnorm(1:10),X3=rnorm(1:10))
dataset2 <- data.frame(names=c("first", "second"), 
X1=rnorm(1:10),X2=rnorm(1:10),X3=rnorm(1:10))

plotdata <- reactive ({get(input$dataset)

if(input$number == "first") {
  filter(plotdata, names=="first")}
else if(input$number == "second") {
  filter(plotdata, names=="second")} 
})

 output$graph <- renderPlot({

datos <- plotdata()

ggplot(datos, aes(X1, X2)) + 
  geom_col()

 })

 }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get the following ***Error: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive')"***

However, when the reactive data section is replaced by the following code, it makes the graph without issues but I would have to define all possible combinations between variables and datasets (which is not an option since the real datasets are 5 with lots of variables and rows to be selected on the UI):

```
plotdata <- reactive ({

if(input$number == "first") {
  filter(dataset1, names=="first")}
else if(input$number == "second") {
  filter(dataset1, names=="second")} 
})
```

So how can I filter from a reactive dataset using dplyr??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(selectInput('number', h4("Select number"), 
                                         choices = c("first", "second")),
                             selectInput('dataset', h4("Select dataset"),
                                         choices=c("dataset1",
                                                   "dataset2"))),
                mainPanel(
                  plotOutput("graph")
                ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)

  dataset1 <- data.frame(names=c("first", "second"), 
                         X1=rnorm(1:10),X2=rnorm(1:10),X3=rnorm(1:10))
  dataset2 <- data.frame(names=c("first", "second"), 
                         X1=rnorm(1:10),X2=rnorm(1:10),X3=rnorm(1:10))

  plotdata <- reactive ({
    dataset <- get(input$dataset)
    dataset %>% filter(names==input$number)
  })

  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    datos <- plotdata()
    ggplot(datos, aes(X1, X2)) + 
      geom_col()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, my advice is to not use `get`, but store your datasets in a named list, so something like `datasets <- list('dataset1'=1, 'dataset2'=2)` and then call with `datasets[[input$dataset]]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer solves this issue in particular; but I will have to make a better question next time because I think I oversimplified the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the reactive data as a function `plotdata()`